My form data is not saving to the database
i am a beginner in django and am creating a cv maker app but i have difficulties adding a new user's detail. from the database the cv is created perfectly but from the design view-template it's not working
here's my vies.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .forms import UserForm

def home(request):
    return render(request, "cv_base/base.html",{
        'users': User.objects.all(),
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_FName = form.cleaned_data['FName'],
            new_LName = form.cleaned_data['LName'],
            new_Email = form.cleaned_data['Email'],
            new_Address = form.cleaned_data['Address'],
            new_Tel = form.cleaned_data['Tel'],
            new_Image = form.cleaned_data['Image'],
            new_Profile = form.cleaned_data['Profile'],
            new_Languages = form.cleaned_data['Languages'],
            new_Profession = form.cleaned_data['Profession'],
            new_Nationality = form.cleaned_data['Nationality'],

            new_User = User.objects.create(
                FName = new_FName,
                LName = new_LName,
                Email = new_Email,
                Address = new_Address,
                Tel = new_Tel,
                Image = new_Image,
                Profile = new_Profile,
                Languages = new_Languages,
                Profession = new_Profession,
                Nationality = new_Nationality,
            )
            new_User.save()
            form = UserForm()
        return render(request, 'cv_base/add.html',{
            'form' : form,
            'success' : True
            })
        
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request,'cv_base/add.html', {'form' : form,})


and here is my forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["FName","LName","Email","Address","Tel","Image","Profile","Languages","Profession","Nationality"]
        labels = {
            'FName' : 'First name',
            'LName' : 'Last name',
            'Email' : 'Your email',
            'Address' : 'Location',
            'Tel' : 'Phone number',
            'Image' : 'Your picture',
            'Profile' : 'Profile',
            'Languages' :'Language spoken',
            'Profession' : 'Profession',
            'Nationality' :'Nationality',
        }
        widgets={
            'FName' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'name'}),
            'LName' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'lName'}),
            'Email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'mail'}),
            'Address' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'loc'}),
            'Tel' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'tel'}),
            'Image' : forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'img'}),
            'Profile' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'Prof'}),
            'Languages' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'Profession' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'profession'}),
            'Nationality' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id' : 'nationality'}),
        }


and lastly where the new user is to be added
 {% extends "cv_base/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- cv display -->
      <h4 class="m-4">All Cv's</h4>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              {% if users %}
              <div class=" container d-flex m-5" style="width: 100%;">  
                  {%for user in users%}
                      <div class=" col-md-4 card border-0 rounded-0 m-3">
                        
                          <img src="{{ new_Image.url }}" alt="{{image.name}}" width="100%" height="150"></img>
                        
                          <div class="card-body text-bg-info">
                              <h5 class="card-title">{{ user.FName|capfirst }}</h5>
                              <h6 class="card-subtitle">{{ user.LName|capfirst }}</h6>
                              <p class="card-text">{{ user.Profile|capfirst }}</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  {%endfor%}
              </div>
           </div>
              {% else %}
              <div class="alert alert-primary ms-4 me-4">Sorry, you don't have any template yet. <a href="{% url 'add' %}" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">Create One?</a></div>
              {% endif %}
  
      </div>
{% endblock %}

this is my create user page
{% extends "cv_base/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
{% if success %}
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    Your CV was created successfully.
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="alert-link">Go to home page</a>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 bg-secondary text-light p-2">
        <form method="POST" class="form p-2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            
                <button class="btn btn-info pe-2" type="submit">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn bg-info"  id="topdf">Download</button>
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
            
        </form>
    </div>
      <!-- cv start -->
      <div class="col-md-8 p-5 book" id="content" style="height: 842px; width: 738px;">
                    
        <div class="container d-flex border" >
            
            <!-- first part start -->
            <div class="col-md-4 first-part mb-4 bg-success">
                <div class="hold d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <!-- rounded image -->
                    <div class="m-2 mt-3">
                        {%load static %}
                        <img src="{{ Image.url }}" id="pictureDestination" style="width: 177px; height: 182px; border-radius: 50%;" class="img-fluid img-hold">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- custom text -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="hold" style="width: 264px;">
                        <div class="mt-4">
                            <ul>
                                <h5 class="text-decoration-underline text-dark-emphasis">Contact</h5>
                                <div class="d-flex"> 
                                    {%load static %} 
                                    <img src="{% static 'phone.svg' %}" class=" pe-1 img-fluid"><li id="telDestination">651190904</li>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex">
                                    {%load static %}
                                    <img src="{% static 'mail.svg' %}"  class=" pe-2 img-fluid" ><li id="emailDestination">rose@gmail.com</li>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex">
                                    {%load static %}
                                    <img src="{% static 'map.svg' %}" class="pe-2 img-fluid"><li id="locDestination">Douala-Bonaberi</li>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <h5 class="text-decoration-underline text-dark-emphasis">Languages</h5>
                                <div id="selectedChoices">
                                    <li id="selectedChoices">French </li>
                                    <li>English </li>
                                    <li>Spanish </li>
                                </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <h5 class="text-decoration-underline text-dark-emphasis">Competences</h5>
                                        <div id="replace">
                                            <li id="replace">Team work</li>
                                            <li>Open minded</li>
                                            <li >Cretivity</li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <h5 class="text-decoration-underline text-dark-emphasis">Hobbies</h5>
                                        <li>Reading</li>  
                                        <li>Singing</li>  
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- end of first part -->
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="class bg-secondary" style=" width: 380px;">   
                            <h3 class="text-white" id="nameDestionation">TOMTAGUE DJOMENI</h3>
                            <h3 class="text-white" id="lNameDestination">ROSE VANELLE</h3>
                            <h6 class="text-white" id="professionDestination">Web developer</h6>
                            <h6 class="text-white" id="nationalityDestination">Cameroonian</h6>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-4 pe-3 ">
                            <div class="main">
                                <h5 class="text-decoration-underline text-secondary">Profile</h5>
                                <p class="text-dark" id="Profile" style="width: 350px;">
                                    Student at Dunamis professional institute, studying software engineering. Passionate by development of new softwares able to revolutionate the world.
                                </p>
                                <h5 class="text-decoration-underline text-secondary">School journey</h5>
                                <p class="text-dark">
                                    <li class="text-dark" id="firstDestination">2010-2011: Fslc at BEL AVENIR </li>
                                    <li class="text-dark" id="olDestination">2022-2023: GCE-Ol at GBHS Bonaberi</li>
                                    <li class="text-dark" id="alDestination">2024-2025: GCE-Al at GBHS Bonaber</li>
                                    
                                </p>
                                <h5 class="w-100 text-decoration-underline text-secondary">Professional experiences</h5>
                                <p class=" text-dark ">
                                    <li class="text-dark" id="piDestination">2010-2011: Fslc at BEL AVENIR </li>
                                    <li class="text-dark" id="aiDestination">2022-2023: GCE-Ol at GBHS Bonaberi</li>
                                </p>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

when i fill it in no error is displayed and nothing is added to the DB. Any suggestions please?
